# How Can I Make The User Vote Only Once

Tags: django

so I'm trying to build a poll app with Django but I have a problem, I can't preventing a user from voting twice or more

This is My Models.py

```
class NewPoll(models.Model):

    Question = models.CharField(max_length=255,default=False)
    option1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    option2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    option3 = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    option1count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    option2count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    option3count = models.IntegerField(default=0)


    created_by= models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='newpoll',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Question
```

What I have in my ***vote*** view in ***views.py***

```
#some codes

@login_required(login_url='signin')
def vote(request,poll_id):
    newpoll = get_object_or_404(NewPoll,pk=poll_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        selected_option = (request.POST['poll'])

        if selected_option == 'option1':
            newpoll.option1count +=1
        elif selected_option == 'option2':
            newpoll.option2count +=1
        elif selected_option == 'option3':
            newpoll.option3count +=1
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Wrong Form!")
        newpoll.save()
        return redirect('result',poll_id=newpoll.pk)
    return render(request,'vote.html',{'newpoll':newpoll})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better off splitting out your Poll, Options and Votes to be separate models. Then you can have uniqueness checks on the vote model [by using the meta option `unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together)

```
class NewPoll(models.Model):

    Question = models.CharField(max_length=255,default=False)

    created_by= models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='poll',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class PollOption(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(NewPoll, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    option = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Vote(models.Model):
    option = models.ForeignKey(PollOption, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['option', 'user']
```